# R expression to plot CI with text and multiple subscripts

Tags: r, plot, text, expression

I'm having trouble writing a particular expression in R that uses complex subscripts. The expression should look like this: $(A_{1,2,L}, A_{1,2,U})$

I have an expression that produces the correct subscripts (example below) but I'm unable to add the comma between the entries. Do I need to use `substitute()` or `group()`?

```
plot(NULL, xlim = c(0, 2), ylim = c(0,2))
text(x = 1, y = 1, label = expression((A["1,2,L"]~A["1,2,U"])))
```

[Output of example without comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhMH4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the two expressions in a list `list(expr1, expr2)`.

```
plot(NULL, xlim = c(0, 2), ylim = c(0,2))

text(x = 1, y = 1, label = expression((list(A["1, 2, L"] , A["1, 2, U"]))))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this while keeping the outer parentheses, too?

Comment: yes, you need to add brackets outside `list( ( expr1, expr2 ))`. Have modifed code above accordingly